# How can I change cursor to wait icon in Visual Studio asp.net?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a Web Forms project in VS 2013 in which I call an asynchronous process from a button within an update panel. I would like the wait icon to show while the asynchronous process is running.

I am using the code- behind shown below, but the cursor does not change from the default pointer when cmdAutoCaption is clicked. However, after the asynchronous process has completed and content_string returned, the cursor changes to a wait icon if it is  moved outside the update panel.

```
 protected void cmdAutoCaption_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {

         string sUser = AuthoriseUser();
         if (sUser == "") return;

         string script1 = "document.body.style.cursor = 'wait';";
         ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script1, true);

         CreateAutoCaption();


     }

     private async void CreateAutoCaption()
     {
         await MakeAnalysisRequestAsync(Session["strImagePath"].ToString());
     }
    private async MakeAnalysisRequestAsync(string imageFilePath)
       {
         ...
      response =  await client.PostAsync(uri, content);
    // Get the JSON response.
      string contentString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        ...
                 string script1 = "document.body.style.cursor = 'auto';";
                 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "ServerControlScript", script1, true);
         ...
       }
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code to change the cursor:

```
Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor
```

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Works for desktop apps but not for Web pages. No System.Windows.Forms assembly which contains Cursor and Cursors objects.